# $SL_2(\mathbf{Z},8\mathbf{Z})$ differs from $E_2(\mathbf{Z},8\mathbf{Z})$. Has this result appeared in the literature?

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, matrices

I know a proof that the congruence subgroup $SL_2(\mathbf{Z},8\mathbf{Z})$ differs from its subgroup $E_2(\mathbf{Z},8\mathbf{Z})$, but can't find this fact in the literature.  Does anyone know a citation for this?

Comment: What is $SL_2(Z,8Z)$? Even if it is meant to be $SL_2(\mathbb Z/8\mathbb Z)$, I still do not know what $E_2$ is.

Comment: If you'd been anyone else I might have suggested asking Bruce Magurn.

Comment: @PeterMueller:  This is standard notation, probably introduced by Bass.  $GL_n(A,I)$ is the kernel of the map $GL_n(A)\rightarrow GL_n(A/I)$ and similarly for $SL$.  $E_n(A,I)$ is the normal subgroup generated by matrices that have ones down the diagonal and a single off-diagonal non-zero entry, with that entry an element of $I$.

Comment: Standard in some circles (algebraic K-theory?)

Comment: Could we hold off on closing a valid research question, please?

Comment: I've read the notation $E_n$ many times and however didn't guess what it was. If the context was explicitly algebraic K-theory this would have been clear but here no clue was given (writing "the congruence subgroup $SL_2(\dots)$ differs from its subgroup $E_2(\dots)$" would have made things clearer at low cost). But even knowing this, I'm not sure whether $E_2(A,I)$ always mean the *normal* subgroup generated by elementary matrices, or if it is sometimes used for the subgroup itself generated by those matrices.

Answer (score 12):

In fact, this holds for any $N$ such that $X=\mathbb{H}^2/PSL_2(\mathbb{Z},N\mathbb{Z})$ has genus $>0$. The point is that the normal subgroup generated by parabolics in $SL_2(\mathbb{Z},N\mathbb{Z})$ will generate the kernel of the map obtained by filling in the cusps of the Riemann surface $X$ to get a closed Riemann surface $\hat{X}$. If $\hat{X}$ has genus $\geq 1$, then the kernel will have infinite index (more generally, if there's torsion, the filling will be an orbifold, which will have non-trivial fundamental group if it has genus $>0$ or more than two orbifold cone points, or two cone points of the same order). In fact, [$X$ has genus $=5$](http://www.mathstat.concordia.ca/faculty/cummins/congruence/csg5M.html#level8).

Actually, the group I've described will contain $E_2(\mathbb{Z},N\mathbb{Z})$, and is the normalizer in $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ of a primitive upper triangular element in $SL_2(\mathbb{Z},N\mathbb{Z})$ . If you take the normalizer in $SL_2(\mathbb{Z},N\mathbb{Z})$, you get an even small subgroup obtained by the kernel of filling in a single cusp of $X$. In this case, one need only show that there are at least 3 cusps, or the genus is $>0$, or there is some combination of elliptic points and cusps which makes the filling have non-trivial fundamental group.

Comment: In fact, this follows for any $N>5$, since the $(2,3,N)$ group will be infinite in this case, and $E_2$ will lie in the kernel of $PSL_2(\mathbb{Z})\to (2,3,N)$.